# how can I set background to react native animated view

Tags: react-native, animation

### Issue Description

I want to change background color right after rendering component but `interpolate` but actual output is `Error: Style property 'backgroundColor' is not supported by native animated module`

### Codes

```
import React, {useEffect, useRef} from 'react';
import {Animated} from 'react-native';

export default function Welcome(props) {
  const translation = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;
  useEffect(() => {
    Animated.timing(translation, {
      toValue: 0,
      duration: 1000,
      useNativeDriver: true,
    }).start();
  }, []);
  const styles = {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: translation.interpolate({
      inputRange: [0, 100],
      outputRange: ['orange', 'blue'],
    }),
    opacity: translation.interpolate({
      inputRange: [25, 50, 100],
      outputRange: [0, 1, 0],
      extrapolate: 'clamp',
    }),
    transform: [
      {translateX: translation},
      {
        rotate: translation.interpolate({
          inputRange: [0, 100],
          outputRange: ['0deg', '360deg'],
        }),
      },
    ],
  };
  return (
    <Animated.View style={styles}>
      <Animated.Text style={{color:'tomato'}}>Credex</Animated.Text>
    </Animated.View>
  );
}
```

Comment: Have you tried setting useNativeDriver: false?

Comment: Whenever I set to ``useNativeDriver: false`` my app crashes

Comment: setting it to false should not crash you app. It seems like you might have a couple of unrelated issues. Have you tried debugging it and determined that it is the interpolation of backgroundColor that causes the crash? I would also consider changing 'orange' and 'blue' to either rgba og hex values.

Answer (score 1):

React native 0.68-rc added support for interpolating colors but you can also use reanimated to do these things and it's much easier. For this case, please set `useNativeDriver` to `false`.

Answer (score 0):

### Solution

- Firstly, I set `useNativeDriver: false`
- Secondly, within use effect

```
 Animated.timing(translation, {
     toValue: 100,
     duration: 1000,
     useNativeDriver: false,
   }).start()
```

- Finally I set height and width to the view

```
  const styles = {
    width: 300,
    height: 300,
    backgroundColor: translation.interpolate({
      inputRange: [0, 100],
      outputRange: ['orange', 'blue'],
    }),
    opacity: translation.interpolate({
      inputRange: [25, 50, 100],
      outputRange: [0, 1, 1],
      extrapolate: 'clamp',
    }),
    transform: [
      {translateY: translation},
      {
        rotate: translation.interpolate({
          inputRange: [0, 100],
          outputRange: ['0deg', '360deg'],
        }),
      },
    ],
  };
```

for more you can refer [to this post Here's](https://eveningkid.medium.com/interpolation-with-react-native-animations-853e467fe5c1) or watch it at [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ybcL8e6ImSo)